# Wordpress loop - get value of custom fields from a custom post type in a category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a page that loops through posts from a custom post type through a category for that custom post ( using Directory Engine Theme )

I tried using wp_query and was able to get the title, but not any other fields
( creating a shortcode in functions.php )

```
add_shortcode("posts_by_category", "shortcode_posts_by_category");
function shortcode_posts_by_category() {
  $query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'place',  // name of post type.
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'place_category',   // taxonomy name
            'field' => 'term_id',           // term_id, slug or name
            'terms' => 94,             // term id, term slug or term name
        )
    )
) );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
?>
<article class="boc">
    <div class="boc__wrapper">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'thumbnail'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="boc__wrapper">
        <h3><?php echo the_title(); ?></h3>
        <div class="content-description">
            <p><?php echo get_post_field('post_content', $post_id); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
<?php
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();}
```

I noticed that the theme being used has a custom object used to create the custom post type so I tried accessing it with no luck `$ae_post_factory`

```
add_shortcode("posts_by_category", "shortcode_posts_by_category");
function shortcode_posts_by_category() {
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'place',  // name of post type.
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'place_category',   // taxonomy name
            'field' => 'term_id',           // term_id, slug or name
            'terms' => 94,             // term id, term slug or term name
        )
        )
    )
);
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
global $ae_post_factory, $user_ID;
$place_obj = $ae_post_factory->get('place');
$address = get_post_meta($query->post->ID, 'address', true);
?>
    <article class="boc">
        <div class="boc__wrapper">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'thumbnail'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="boc__wrapper">
        <h3><?php echo the_title(); ?></h3>
        <div class="content-description">
            <p><?php echo $address ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
<?php
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();}
```

I did a dump of the `$place_obj` and this is what I got
( sorry about formatting - adding array as code snippet didn't work 0:) )

```html
AE_Posts Object (
  [meta] => Array (
    [0] => address
    [1] => avatar
    [2] => post_count
    [3] => comment_count
    [4] => et_featured
    [5] => et_expired_date
    [6] => et_paid
    [7] => et_phone
    [8] => et_emailaddress
    [9] => et_url
    [10] => et_fb_url
    [11] => et_google_url
    [12] => et_twitter_url
    [13] => et_video
    [14] => et_full_location
    [15] => et_location_lat
    [16] => et_location_lng
    [17] => open_time
    [18] => close_time
    [19] => serve_day
    [20] => serve_time
    [21] => cover_image
    [22] => cover_image_url
    [23] => video_position
    [24] => reject_message
    [25] => et_ad_order
    [26] => rating_score
    [27] => rating_score_comment
    [28] => reviews_count
    [29] => et_payment_package
    [30] => et_featured
    [31] => et_claimable
    [32] => et_claim_approve
    [33] => et_claim_info
  )
  [current_post] => 
  [current_main_post] => 
  [wp_query] => 
  [post_type] => place
  [taxs] => Array (
    [0] => place_category
    [1] => location
  )
  [convert] => Array (
    [0] => post_parent
    [1] => post_title
    [2] => post_name
    [3] => post_content
    [4] => post_excerpt
    [5] => post_author
    [6] => post_status
    [7] => ID
    [8] => post_type
    [9] => comment_count
    [10] => guid
  )
  [localize] => Array (
  )
)
```

#### What I Hope To Do

I need to access the 'place' custom post type and create a query loop that shows 5 posts by category in that custom post type. Then output custom fields such as title, address, post content, featured image etc.

Really appreciate your time. I've been struggling with this for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can able to get all the fields that by default comes with a Post except the meta fields value. I found a small issue in your code where you are trying to get the Featured image,

`<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'thumbnail'); ?>`

`<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail'); ?>`

inside loop you dont need the post id as a parameter, even the function dont accept the id as a parameter. The function will print the url only. You need to set it to an image tag. like below :

```
<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail'); ?>">
```

If you need to get the post meta values you can use the below code for your refernce :

```
$variable_name = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '<field_name>', true);
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: also you dont need to write echo with the_title() it automatically echoed the title.